# Righting moment of a flattened balloon

Tags: aerodynamics

Would a flattened round balloon tend to orient vertically or horizontally, assuming neutral buoyancy? Does this shape provide a righting moment against pitch and roll?

By flattened, I do not mean “flat”. It is simply smaller in one axis than the others, by some arbitrary measure.

Comment: The heaviest point will be at the bottom.

Comment: Assuming the material is as nearly uniform as possible and the balloon itself is radically symmetrical, what then?